# Parse JSON to JSONP on the fly without using third parties

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp

I am trying to access the codeforces api and they are providing a JSON(but not JSONP) as I'm making a cross domain request, it should be JSONP.

So, I'm using a third party [json2jsonp](http://json2jsonp.com), and it works.

```
var cfurl = "http://json2jsonp.com/?url=http://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=";
var runUserRequest = function(handle){
    return $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: cfurl + handle + "&callback=cfhandle"
    })
}
```

Finally, my doubt is is there some elegant way to do this without using the third parties like [json2jsonp](http://json2jsonp.com)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there some elegant way to do this without using the third parties like json2jsonp

Use one of the following options:

- A reverse proxy server
- A greasemonkey script
- Browser settings

**References**

- [Long Polling Options: Nginx, PHP, Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839295/long-polling-options-nginx-php-node-js)
- [Cross-domain post with Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275378/cross-domain-post-with-greasemonkey/11275659#11275659)
- [how can I deactivate cross-site scripting defense on my own browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447499/how-can-i-deactivate-cross-site-scripting-defense-on-my-own-browser/5200028#5200028)
- [How do I disable the access denied message when trying to do cross scripting into an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293418/how-do-i-disable-the-access-denied-message-when-trying-to-do-cross-scripting-int/6293503#6293503)